# Why do my bootstrap inputs Are bigger than their parents div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi i am trying to do simple login site but i have some problems with bootstrap. I am trying to do a simple div in the center of my site, but the problem is that when i add more than two inputs, inputs doesnt scale and they are bigger than div. The problem is on smaller screnns. 
Here is html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class='container'>
   <form id='login'>
    <div class='form-group row'>
     <label for='email' class='col-form-label'></label>
     <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
      <input type="email" id='login' class='form-control' placeholder="login">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group row'>
     <label for='password' class='col-form-label'></label>
     <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
      <input type="password" class='form-control' id='password' placeholder="password">
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and here is my css code:

```css
body {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 height: 100vh;
}
.container {
 background-color: #3b5f83;
 position: relative;
 top: 40%;
 height: 20%;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
}
#login {
 max-height: 60%;
}
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size sm isn't the smallest mobile view.

Replace all instances of

```
    col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4
```

with

```
    col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-4
```

and your inputs will stay inside your element on smaller sizes

Comment: But is it possible to make that elements inside div get smaller automatically?

Comment: or my div element get bigger ?

Comment: you mean without the col-* classes? what do you mean by automatically?

Comment: i mean that you know when you give extra input, that div in center get bigger but it is ok, beacues i had height: 20%; so that was a problem, but i have got another because now the content is not in the center

Comment: never mind sorry for trouble, everything works just now :D

Comment: happy to hear that!